# android get current location return wrong latlng in some devices which connect with mobile data network

Tags: android, location

If I connect to network with wifi, code below return right latlng but if I connect with mobile data gprs it return wrong location about 300 meters.
it happens in some devices not all of them, like Huawei G730

```
private LocationListener     mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public synchronized void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
        strLatLng = l.getLatitude()+","+l.getLongitude();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
    }

   };
```

when I request to get user current location :

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
```

why it happens and how can I make it right?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: isn't obvious? how make it right? and why it happens

Comment: Do you request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission ?

Comment: yes, permissions are done, It works fine, but in some devices it returns wrong location and just only the device connect to network with mobile data not wifi

Comment: It happens as explained in my answer, now the part to make it right, you can fix it to a certain degree that is if you enforce to use GPS for accurate location apart from that Network/Data acquired location are not as accurate as GPS and not all device will behave equally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes correct the Location acquired from Network/Data would be off by a few meters with the actual location if verified by location acquired by GPS.

The variation is because it is purely on the Manufacture Side, Android does not enforce manufactures to use specific hardware for its devices, hence we have variation in the out put especially dealing with hardware peripherals such as location, orientation, proximity e.t.c

Comment: so noway to get right location in such devices when connect with mobile data?

Comment: From my experience no, if my answer and comments we helpful please accept them. Cheers.

Comment: thanks, lets see others answers than I 'll accept it